# "None" shows instead name of object Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have such an error: in my models there is two ones: subject and section. In section-model there is a field where saved every subject in this section.

```
class Section(models.Model):
    """Model for a section."""
    ename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    definition = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="physics/section", blank=True)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField("Subject")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Subject(models.Model):
    """Model for a subject in section."""
    ename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    definition = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am trying to show every subject in the section. My views and template below:
views:

```
def section(request, section_name):
    section = get_object_or_404(Section, ename=section_name)
    return render(request, 'section.html', {'section': section})
```

template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{{ section.name }}
{{ section.subjects }}
{% endblock content %}
```

But "None" shows in the page of this section. It looks so:

**(real subject name here) Physics.Subject.None**

Can anybody say what's wrong? Thank you, in advance for attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a ManyToManyField to reference your `Section` you need to access that set in your template and then pull information from it.

Something like this should suffice:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{{ section.name }}
{% for subject in section.subjects_set.all %}
{{ subject.name }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```